# SQL SUM and CASE and DISTINCT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I've been trying to re-do this statement but to no avail.

```
SELECT b.Program AS Program,
    SUM(CASE WHEN a.Gender LIKE 'M%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Males,    
    SUM(CASE WHEN a.Gender LIKE 'F%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Females,
    SUM(CASE WHEN e.Activity LIKE 'Arts' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Arts,
    AVG(CASE WHEN a.Gender LIKE 'M%' THEN CAST(f.Score AS DEC(10,2)) ELSE NULL END)
AS MalesAverage
FROM tblChildren a
    LEFT JOIN tblInvolvement b ON b.ChildID = a.ChildID
    LEFT JOIN tblActivities e ON e.ChildID = b.ChildID
    LEFT JOIN tblScores f ON f.ChildID = b.ChildID
WHERE b.Place = 'Location'
    AND b.Program = 'Program'
    AND b.Year = '2009-10'
    AND f.Assessment LIKE '%Pre%Assessment%'
    AND e.StudentID = b.StudentID
GROUP BY Program
```

Now I will get results like:

```
Program Males Females Arts MalesAverage
---------------------------------------
Program 7     5       1    50.000000
```

The problem with this is that there are only 4 males and 3 females, and that when I add the tblActivites, it seems to give duplicates. After looking through I noticed that there were 12 ChildID's in the Activities table, the reason being those Children were tied to more than one activity. I tried using something like:

```
SELECT SUM( DISTINCT CASE WHEN a.Gender LIKE 'M%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Males
```

However it just returned 1 under the Males column. Any help would be appreciated. And just to clarify further, the tables are keyed together via the ChildID, I just need help making sure that I am returning the right information. If this is solved then my massive list of these things will be solved. Avoiding GROUP BY for everything is preferred seeing as I have a lot of data.

Comment: @niktrs As explained in response below that still gives 7 males, when the proper results should be 4.

Comment: check the relations among the table and the join's. Run the query without the aggregates and check the result for anything strange.

Comment: I had the same issue as you. You can't do a SUM with a distinct here, because it'll just keep one row and return you 1, like you saw. You need to be using COUNT DISTINCT like Dave suggested below which will then weed out the unqualified fields and count the remaining.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Would this work?

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a.Gender LIKE 'M%' THEN a.ChildID ELSE NULL END) AS Males
```

I suspect there are better ways to do the join overall, but without knowing a lot more about the schema I really don't know.

Comment: What exactly do you need to know. I can give more generic names than what I actually have seeing as these are already generic not real table names.

Comment: I'd start with, what are the primary keys of those tables?  But I think the COUNT expression I gave will address your immediate problem.

Comment: This works however I also might need some clarification for the AVG aggregate function however I appreciate your help very much.

Answer (score 0):

**You don't show the source data, but I'm willing to bet you have multiple rows per person per program.**

You `GROUP BY Program` which aggregates per program, but if say `John Smith` has two rows with that program ID, he will  get counted as `MALE` twice.

Please show us your table structure so we can give you a clearer query.  Ideally you will get the count from a subselect using a `GROUP BY` on something like `Person_ID` so that you don't get duplicate counts.

Comment: This is what I was trying to avoid. The program isn't the problem however. "After looking through I noticed that there were 12 ChildID's in the Activities table, the reason being those Children were tied to more than one activity". As I stated, this is the problem, the child is tied to more than one activity at once producing identical ChildID's in the tblActivities which has 2 columns. ChildID and Activity. I would like to try and avoid the GROUP BY however, but if it's unavoidable then I guess I can do that.